# CSS div style question

Tags: css, html

what is the proper code for this?

[image]

in div style code. I know how to use float but only 2 divides. But in 4 divides, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `float: left` for every div.

Answer (score 4):

Just `float` them all `left` and if necessary add a `right` `margin` of `-1px` so that the borders overlap nicely. Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2684578</title>
        <style>
            .box {
                float: left;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                margin-right: -1px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">box1</div>
        <div class="box">box2</div>
        <div class="box">box3</div>
        <div class="box">box4</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As long as body is wide enough to fit.

Answer (score 3):

Floating will still work for any number of div's, they'll line up next to each other until they fill the width of the container, at which point they will start to wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want your 4 divs to wrap to the next line when the window gets resized you can place your 4 divs inside a parent div and set the width of that parent div.

Here is an example based on BalusC's code above:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2684578</title>
        <style>
            .box {
                float: left;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                margin-right: -1px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            .parent {
                width: 404px;
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="box">box1</div>
            <div class="box">box2</div>
            <div class="box">box3</div>
            <div class="box">box4</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```